# How to implement recursive function with two inputs using lambda expressions?

Tags: java, recursion, lambda, java-8

I was trying to implement recursion using the lambda function in java-8. With the documentation present and the resources found online, I am able to make the recursive call with a single parameter in the function.

Refer the below code snippet -

```
    private static final IntToLongFunction fact = x  -> x == 0 ? 1L : x*MyTestClass.fact.applyAsLong(x-1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(fact.applyAsLong(4));
    }
```

Now I am trying to have something similar to above code snippet for the following use case where I m trying to find out the gcd of two numbers -

```
// Normal recusive meethod for finding gcd
    private static long gcd(long a, long b){
        return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b);
    }
```

I have tried using a function interface to do so, but no luck with it.

> Function <Long, Long> gcd = (Long a, Long b) -> b == 0 ? a : this.gcd.apply(b);

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to make a function that takes two `Long` arguments and returns a `Long`.

A `Function <Long, Long>` is a function that takes *one* `Long` argument and returns a `Long`. So not the right functional interface for your purpose. Instead I think you want a `BiFunction<Long, Long, Long>`. Or for brevity you may use `BinaryOperator<Long>` to mean the same.

A `BiFunction` is, from the documentation:

> Represents a function that accepts two arguments and produces a
> result.

And a `BinaryOperator`:

> Represents an operation upon two operands of the same type, producing
> a result of the same type as the operands. This is a specialization of
> `BiFunction` for the case where the operands and the result are all of
> the same type.

Also if you want your function to take two arguments, you need to pass two arguments to `this.gcd.apply()`. Then you should be set.

**Links**

- [Documentation of `BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html).
- [Documentation of `BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html).